# a user to ubuntu server from PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, sudo

Im currently trying to make it so a user can be added from a PHP interface on an Ubuntu web server of mine.
I have this file on the server

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);



if(!empty($_GET) && !empty($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['mem']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    $mem = $_GET['mem'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $user =  escapeshellarg($user.$id);

    echo $user; 
    echo $mem;
    echo $id; 

    $output = shell_exec('sudo useradd $user');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
}


?>
```

The echos and error reporting are just for debugging.
in my /etc/sudoers file i have this line

```
www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/useradd
```

and ttl is not required. Does anybody know why this doesnt work?

Comment: Giving your webserver root access seems like a [really bad idea](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Acatastrophic)

Comment: i understand the implications but its only for the useradd command, and the only way to access the web server is by tunnelling into a VPN, the web server is blocked by a firewall rule on its external IP.

Comment: could you define "this doesn't work". Does your screen explode? Do you get the error "syntax error on line 3", what happened when you debugged that line?

Comment: literally nothing happens, no user is create, no home directory is created, no output is given, no log files indicate anything. but as Nanne said, i was using an incorrect syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo useradd $user');
```

will NOT insert `$user` in that string but will literally execute that string. use

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo useradd $user");
```

Comment: Thankyou for that. EDIT: that actually fixed the whole issue, thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

First, I agree with Jamie Taylor : executing shell commands as root seems like a bad idea.

Second, when you use the useradd command, you need to manually input a password. This is done on purpose on Ubuntu.

You can bypass this using the --geckos option.

Here is the command :

```
adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" username
```

(Credits to https://askubuntu.com/questions/94060/run-adduser-non-interactively for the gecos part.)

Comment: If you have a better method im all ears